# Apply an expression to each array element in document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got a sample document that I'm trying to project within a MongoDB aggregate pipeline. I'm testing with a single document that looks roughly like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "title" : "Questions",
    "sortIndex" : 0,
    "topics" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "title" : "Creating a Question",
            "sortIndex" : 1,
            "thumbnail" : "CreatingAQuestion.jpg",
            "seenBy" : [ "user101", "user202" ],
            "pages" : [ 
                {
                    "visual" : "SelectPlanets.gif",
                    "text" : "Some Markdown"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "",
            "title" : "Deleting a Question",
            "sortIndex" : 0,
            "thumbnail" : "DeletingAQuestion.jpg",
            "seenBy" : [ "user101" ],
            "pages" : [ 
                {
                    "visual" : "SelectCard.gif",
                    "text" : "Some Markdown"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The output I'm trying to obtain is something along these lines:

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "title" : "Questions",
    "topics" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Creating a Question",
            "thumbnail" : "CreatingAQuestion.jpg",
            "seen" : true
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Deleting a Question",
            "thumbnail" : "DeletingAQuestion.jpg",
            "seen" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

Specifically the bit I'm struggling with is the `seen` flag.

I've read the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which state:

> When projecting or adding/resetting a field  within an embedded document...
>
> ... Or you can nest the fields:
>
> `contact: { address: { country: <1 or 0 or expression> } }`

I wish to use an **expression** and I took note of the following:

> When nesting the fields, you cannot use dot notation inside the embedded document to specify the field, e.g. contact: `{ "address.country": <1 or 0 or expression> }` is invalid.

So I'm trying to work out how to "reference" a subdocument field within an expression. That quote suggests I can't use *dot notation* but when I can't seem to get it working with nested notation either. Here's what I've got so far:

```
db
    .getCollection('chapters')
    .aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                title: 1,
                topics: {
                    title: 1,
                    thumbnail: 1,
                    publishedAt: 1,
                    test: "$seenBy",
                    seen: { $in: ["user202", "$seenBy"] },
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

So I've hard coded `user202` into my query for now, and expected to see **true** and **false** for the 2 documents. I've also put in a `test` field to map out the `seenBy` field from the sub-document. What this produces is:

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "title" : "Questions",
    "topics" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Creating a Question",
            "thumbnail" : "CreatingAQuestion.jpg",
            "test" : [ 
                "user101", 
                "user202"
            ],
            "seen" : true
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Deleting a Question",
            "thumbnail" : "DeletingAQuestion.jpg",
            "test" : [ 
                "user101", 
                "user202"
            ],
            "seen" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

So obviously my "$seenBy" isn't accessing the correct topic because the `test` field contains the data from the 1st document.

So ultimately my question is, how can I access the `seenBy` field within a subdocument, referring to the **current** subdocument so I can create an expression?

*Note:* I have got this working with multiple `$project` and an `$unwind` but wanted to try compress/clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) here. Simply notating the array in projection ( which is a bit of a boon since MongoDB 3.2 ) does not really cut it when you need a localized value for the current element. That is what you need and it's what [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) provides:

```
db.getCollection('chapters').aggregate([
   { $project: {
     title: 1,
     topics: {
       $map: {
         input: "$topics",
         as: "t",
         in: {
           title: "$$t.title",
           thumbnail: "$$t.thumbnail",
           publishedAt: "$$t.publishedAt",
           test: "$$t.seenBy",
           seen: { $in: ["user202", "$$t.seenBy"] },
        }
      }
   }}
])
```

So for each element the current value of `"seenBy"` as a property is being tested by the expression. Without the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) that is not possible, and you can only really notate the "whole" array. Which is really not what you want to test here.

Comment: That's great thanks, hadn't used `$map` before but makes perfect sense that it fits the usage when you think about it. I think the docs just led me down the wrong path as it sounded like I should be able to do what I wanted.